# How GitHub git CLI authenticate using SSO without Browser

Tags: git, github, single-sign-on

I am using "git" CLI on a machine behind a proxy.

In the .gitconfig file I have configured the *http* and *proxy* section parameters, so all fine in the sense that I can access GitHub from command line.

However since the GitHub Organization has SAML SSO (+ 2FA) enabled, during e.g. a "git clone" command the process asks to sign in with Browser because of the SSO. However I need to proceed without the possibility to use a Browser (because the Browser has no proxy configuration..).
Is there a mechanism to achieve that?

thanks

Comment: Setting an API token in the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable doesn't work?

Comment: By just setting an env does NOT work. But I got an idea to try: I think it can work if you authorize the token as described here (and this can be done out-of-band) https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on/authorizing-a-personal-access-token-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headless auth can be done with `--with-token`

From GitHub's [gh auth login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login):

> ```
> # authenticate against github.com by reading the token from a file
> $ gh auth login --with-token < mytoken.txt
> ```

If you're using fine grain tokens this should just work.

If you have a classic token you'll need to authorize it. This is explained in the GitHub's official [Authorizing a personal access token for use with SAML single sign-on](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on/authorizing-a-personal-access-token-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on).

---

It's a good idea to clear with the person responsible for security that there will be a setup where 2FA **is not** used when the policy **is** to use 2FA. You may, for example, be required to use a token linked to a dedicated service account, not to your personal account.

Comment: Many thanks, this works! Just to make sure I understand your last comment of 2FA. Are you saying that 2FA will not trigger in the signing process (i.e. when the token gets manually authorized) even if 2FA is enabled?